# groupby columns in awk

Tags: python, awk

Hello I'd like to convert a python script in awk, how to do a group by in columns from a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv") 
res0 = df.groupby("genes").agg({'start':'count'}).reset_index()
res0
```

How to do this using awk or sh?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please add sample input from data.csv (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Sorry for not providing a sample dataset. @jared_mamrot understand my request. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details it's difficult to help you; does this solve your problem?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
cat test.csv
genes,timepoint,value
P53,1,3.1
P53,2,3.2
P53,3,4.5
P53,4,5.1
P53,5,6.6
TRIM43,1,44
TRIM43,2,50
TRIM43,3,55
TRIM43,4,60
TRIM43,5,67
GAPDH,1,0.1
GAPDH,2,0.1
GAPDH,3,0.1
GAPDH,4,0.1
GAPDH,5,0.1
```

Run the python script

```
cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
res0 = df.groupby("genes").agg({'value':'count'}).reset_index()
print(res0)

./test.py
    genes  value
0   GAPDH      5
1     P53      5
2  TRIM43      5
```

Replicate it with awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS="\t"}
     NR==1 {print "genes","value"}
     NR>1 {genes[$1]++}
     END {for (i in genes)
              print i, genes[i]
     }' test.csv
genes   value
GAPDH   5
TRIM43  5
P53     5
```